# Release to just iOS8+?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Is it possible to release to just iOS8+? In the XCode iOS Deployment Target setting, running the latest XCode update from the store, the dropdown numbers go up to 7.1 but not above (I can manually enter 8.0, but not sure that would pass the validation when submitting to the store).

Our main goal with this deployment target is trying to exclude iPhone 4 from the supported devices, and to require a minimum of iPhone 4s.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you scrolled the list? On mine 7.1 shows selected at the top... but I can scroll further up the list.

Answer (score 3):

### Xcode 5.1.1

it doesnot show for ios 8.0 in dropdown selection

[image]

### Xcode 6.0

it shows for ios 8.0 in dropdown selection

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Apparently the Mac Store XCode update functionality didn't actually update to the latest -- will search the developer downloads section for betas!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can submit apps that have a Deployment Target of iOS 8.0. You can even select 8.0 in Xcode if you scroll the list. It's there.